# Can be the function of Port Forwarding can be attained through IPV6?

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunneling

I have a small server for my own purpose. I use SQL server in it and access the server through another computer via WAN...

But my Internet provider doesn't allow port forwarding options...

But the Internet provider supports ipv6 tunneling...

Is it possible to do the same function of port forwarding with ipv6

Comment: Port forwarding is used for the NAPT variant of NAT on IPv4. IPv6 uses global addressing, so there is no NAT because each host can have a public address. You must also make sure that there is a proper rule for any firewall.

Comment: so then it is possible to do so?